# redirected to a different page after submit validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my php code `echo "joined";` after everything works correctly and echo other messages if there was an error, when everything is submitted I want the user to be redirected to another page but it doesn't, when I click on submit it echos "joined" everything gets checked and submitted to the database but I need click on it a second time to get redirected to the other page.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {
            $("#ack").empty();
            $("#ack").html(info);
        });
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    var ack = $("#ack").text();
    if (ack.match('joined')) {
        window.location.replace("user-login.php");
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the action script in your form? what does it do?

Comment: @Lambda7 after I hit the submit button in myForm it checks the data submitted with php, echos a message based on if there was an error or everything was done correctly and loads the message to the div with the id = "ack"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$.post()` is an asynchronous function, and you treated your code as synchronous.

In other words, when the browser reaches this line:

```
var ack = $("#ack").text();
if (ack.match('joined')) {
    window.location.replace("user-login.php");
}
```

the `POST` call has not finished yet, so the `if` is not happening.

So you need to move this logic in the 'success' callback of the `$.post()` function:

```
$.post(
    $("#myForm").attr("action"),
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info) {
        $("#ack").empty();
        $("#ack").html(info);
        if(info.match('joined')) {
            window.location.replace("user-login.php");
        }
    }
);
```